# In PyParsing, how to convert an optional parse result to an integer or None if not present

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm writing a class `PortRange` with a built-in `parse` method:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, Optional, Suppress

class PortRange(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end if end is not None else self.start

    @staticmethod
    def parse(string):
        port = Word(nums)
        assignmentExpr = port.setResultsName('start') + Optional(Suppress("-") + port.setResultsName('end'))
        assignmentTokens = assignmentExpr.parseString(string)
        start = int(assignmentTokens.start)
        end = int(assignmentTokens.end)
        return PortRange(start=start, end=end)
```

The `PortRange` object has `start` and `end` attributes, and if the `end` is given as `None` in the constructor, it is assumed to be the same as the start.

The `PortRange` also has a string representation: if the `start` and `end` are equal, it is just one number, whereas if they are different they are separated by a hyphen (e.g., `5-10`). I'm trying to write a `parse` method which parses correctly both cases using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation). To this end, I've written the following tests:

```
import pytest

'''Tests'''
def test_parse_full_port_range():               # This passes
    port_range = PortRange.parse("5-10")
    assert port_range.start == 5
    assert port_range.end == 10

def test_parse_port_range_with_start_only():    # This fails
    port_range = PortRange.parse("5")
    assert port_range.start == 5
    assert port_range.end == 5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

The problem is that the second test fails, because you end up trying to do

```
int('')
```

which leads to a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. Within the `parse` function, I would like `end` to become `None`, similar to what it would be if I were to write a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with symbolic group names and use `groupdict()`.

How can I achieve this? (I tried redefining `port` as `port = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda x: int(x))`, but this leads to a `TypeError` due to 0 arguments into the `lambda`).

Comment: What version of pyparsing are you using?

Comment: Here is a link to a jupyter notebook I used to present a similar parser to the Austin Evening of Python Coding meetup: http://www.ptmcg.com/files/EoPC_pyparsing.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assignementTokens seems to be a list of strings. Instead of .start and .end atrributes, I used [0] and [-1] for the start and end. In the case with the parse argument is "5", both start and end are set to 5 (integer).

```
start = int(assignmentTokens[0])
end = int(assignmentTokens[-1])
```

Comment: If you do `print(assignmentTokens.dump())` you will see both the list and name structures of the parsed data. If there is no end value given, then `assignmentTokens.end` evaluates to `""`, which is why int has a problem. While this solution works, you will do better in the long run getting your head around using results names.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Getting started with PyParsing](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514235.do), the `ParseResults.ParseResults` class supports simple list-based access (used in the answer above) as well as dict-style and object attribute-style access to named fields within the results. It seems like the dict-style access returns a `KeyError` if the optional field was not parsed. So I used the dictionary's [get method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) to ensure that `None` is the default for `end`:

```
    start = int(assignmentTokens['start'])
    end = assignmentTokens.get('end', None)
    end = int(end) if end is not None else None
```

This also makes both tests pass.